# File does not upload when on mobile, but works on desktop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

This is my blade code:

```html
<form action="{{ route('picture.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <input type="file" name="fotoRemolque" id="fotoRemolque"
    placeholder="Tomar Foto de Remolque" class="inputsLogin"
    multiple capture="camera" accept="image/*">

    @error('fotoRemolque')
        <small class=" text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
    <br>
    <div class="col-12 text-center margen">
        <h3 >Numero de Remolque:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="remolque" id="result" class="inputRemolqueContenedor" readonly>
        @error('remolque')
            <small class=" text-danger"> {{$message}}</small>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="EnviarImagen" id="enviarImg" class="btnEnviarImagen">
</form>
```

And here is my controller:

```php
$request->validate([
    'fotoRemolque' => 'required|image',
    'remolque' => 'required|string'
]);

$remolque = $request->input('remolque');


$nombre = Auth::user()->username;
$terminal = Auth::user()->terminal;
$fecha = Carbon::now();
$pictureName = $nombre.$terminal.$remolque.$fecha.".png";
$images = $request->file('fotoRemolque')->store('public/imagesTrailers');
$url = Storage::url($images);
$url = Str::after( $url, 'http://localhost');


$picture = new Picture();

$picture->username = $nombre;
$picture->terminal = $terminal;
$picture->trailer = $remolque;
$picture->date = $fecha;
$picture->image_url = $url;

$picture->save();
```

The problem happens only on the mobile view, it doesn't upload the file, here is the problem:

[image: error wiht mobile view]

I have the app in windows server 2012

Comment: I already changed 
post_max_size = 2048M
memory_limit = 2048M
max_input_time = 300
upload_max_filesize = 2048
in the php.ini file and the problem continues

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the selected file(s) are even sent to the server?

Comment: I think the files doesnt sent to the server on mobile because in pc are sent good